# Game loading Javascript

Tags: javascript, loading

I am looking for a script that shows my logo while loading the game and shows the loading percentage or a bar representing how much of the game is loaded, and then makes my logo disappear once the game is loaded.

e-g like this site has used http://www.gamegape.com/en-2095-elemental-battles.html

If something like this is not available, can someone at least tell me how this site has done it, so I could copy it from them?

Comment: So I'm guessing you made this game yourself? If you did, you know JavaScritp and would have a good idea of how to make this. You might be struggling with it; if that's the case, post your code and we will help.

Comment: I have not developed the game, i am games publisher, i do have control over the games side server, as they are uploaded by me, i have seen a few sites using scripts to do this thing, and they are not faking it, it actually shows the real loading, but i don't know how they do it with scripts?

Comment: You will need internal access to the Flash file to do this. That site put the preloader in the game itself.

Answer (score 2):

This might help. Its a JavaScript Preloader for HTML5 Apps

http://thinkpixellab.com/pxloader/

have alook at the smples page.

Comment: Hi, thanks for reply Well i don't want to fake it, i want it to actually show how much is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

The site you have mentioned is using flash, well this can easily be achieved by js or css3 itself.

Check this eaxample out for a progress bar http://ivanvanderbyl.com/.

You can either add animations using jquery or by css3.

Comment: thanks for the beautiful css3, i love when it comes to css ^_^ but the thing is i don't want to display fake loading, i want to show actual thing.

Comment: Well it is not a fake progress bar, if you read it properly it actually depends upon the page load progress i.e you show the progress based on different sections you load. Take a look at this https://github.com/ivanvanderbyl/ui-progress-bar/blob/master/source/javascripts/application.js.coffee

Comment: can you make any example with .swf file i-e it doesn't show the flash until it is 100% loaded. As i tried and i failed, i don't where did i went wrong.

Comment: plus the bar doesn't vanish when its 100% loaded, its another issue with it, as what it should have actually done is that after loading it should have disappeared